# LiveCycle Highlighting when Changed from Default

Tags: adobe, livecycle, defaults

I have a large form that has already been made, there are many different objects in the form including drop downs and check boxes. The majority of the objects are check boxes. I need the boxes to turn red if they are changed from the default. Some defaults are "on" others are "off" I can do this item by item, but it's very time consuming. Is there a way to make it a standard for the form?

The other issue I am having is, if they change it from the default it turns red, however if it is returned to the default it stays red, is there a way to make it change back? I feel like this should be something simple that I am just missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scripting on enter and exit events

In Adobe LiveCycle Designer select all the fields you want to change the highlighting and add the following scripts to each text field:

Add an enter event to the fields to highlight in red:

```
field1.border.edge.color.value = "255,0,0";
field2.border.edge.color.value = "255,0,0";
```

Add an exit event to the fields to highlight in black:

```
field1.border.edge.color.value = "255,255,255";
field2.border.edge.color.value = "255,255,255";
```